# Why do you have to wrap object attribute in a block to check if it raises an error?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm currently reading [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/writing-an-api-wrapper-in-ruby-with-tdd--net-23875) tutorial. Inside "dynamic attributes" section, it tells you to wrap your minitest spec inside a block to check if overwritten method_missing raises `NoMethodError` on fictional attributes. I'm using RSpec and the [docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher) show the exact same pattern:

```
RSpec.describe "calling a missing method" do
  it "raises" do
    expect { Object.new.foo }.to raise_error(NameError)
  end
end
```

My specs:

Passing spec

```
it "raises a method missing error if attribute is not present" do
  expect { coin.imaginary_attribute }.to raise_error(NoMethodError)
end
```

Failing spec

```
it "raises a method missing error if attribute is not present" do
  expect(coin.imaginary_attribute).to raise_error(NoMethodError)
end
```

Error message:

```
NoMethodError:
      undefined method `imaginary_attribute'
```

I tested it without using the block, and as expected the test fails. What's the reason behind it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrap the code in the block so that `expect` can control when to call your code. In pseudo-ruby, it looks like this:

```
def expect(&block)
  begin
    block.call
  rescue => ex
    save_exception_for_assertions(ex)
  end
end
```

This does two things:

1. Intercepts the exception, so that it's available for the matchers
2. Makes sure that exception does not affect spec execution (because it is *expected*).

In contrast, the other variant that you tried

```
 expect(coin.imaginary_attribute).to raise_error(NoMethodError)
```

`coin.imaginary_attribute` is evaluated BEFORE `expect` is called (because here it is a regular argument in a method call). So `expect` doesn't have a chance to intercept the exception, and your spec crashes.